# How to get a Facebook Page's access token without having a `redirect_uri` using libcURL in AutoIt3?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, scripting, libcurl, autoit

How can I get a Facebook Page's access token by using **libcURL** without having an actual `redirect_uri` ?

The scripting language that I'm using is *AutoIt3*. And also, I already have a specific **libcURL UDF**.

Please show some updated example scripts.

Comment: you need an `auth_token` to get an `access_token`. To get the `auth_token`, there must be a `redirect_uri`

Comment: @deadlock What if my `redirect_uri` is *https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html* ?

Comment: It will pass the `auth_token` to that url. You have to make the `redirect_uri` point to your script so that you can capture the `auth_token`.

Comment: @deadlock You mean the `auth_token` will be a value of the query string of the `redirect_uri` ? But my plan is just to create a standalone macro without having web app.

Comment: yea it's gonna be in a query string parameter called `code`. You can't do anything more than that using FB graph API. If you want it to be a stand alone solution, you can try using a headless browser testing framework like CasperJS or PhantomJS.